# Is it possible to set IE compatibility for all pages except one?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, internet-explorer

I'm working on a legacy application which has the unfortunate need to rely on older version of IE to function correctly. Within this application I have added a page that uses HTML5/CSS3 and modern JavaScript libraries to render and function. This page has been given the meta tag:

```
http-equiv="X-UA-Compatbile" content="IE-Edge"
```

Unfortunately this page does not render correctly. The application is an older ASP.Net system that I'm running on localhost IIS. The path for the app is

```
http://localhost/csa/myappname
```

and to the problematic page the path is

```
http://localhost/csa/myappname/Responsive_Dashboard.aspx
```

I have attempted the following:

1. Set the browser document mode to Edge using the F12 developer tools. This works for my page but breaks the rest of the application.
2. Updated the local sites.xml file with the Enterprise Mode Site List Manager, giving older browser compatibility to the

   ```
   http://localhost/csa/myappname
   ```

   and IE11 document mode to my page at

   ```
   http://localhost/csa/myappname/Responsive_Dashboard.aspx
   ```

   then set the browser profile to Enterprise using the F12 developer tools. In this case, the application works fine except for my page, which does not change the document mode.
3. Set the browser compatibility mode for `localhost` via the IE Compatibility View settings, and changed the browser profile to `desktop`. The results here are the same as in item #2.

Is there a way to set my page at

```
http://localhost/csa/myappname/Responsive_Dashboard.aspx
```

to use the latest rendering engine while leaving the rest of the application/site alone? The only way I can get this to work is to use the F12 menu to switch the document mode back and forth. This would not be an acceptable solution for my business partners. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to put that tag inside your HTML page? Inside HTML Head > `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

Comment: Yes - the first part of the page looks like this `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

Comment: Where is that meta tag is set? Do you use master page?

Comment: That tag is set directly on the page I noted - on Responsive_Dashboard.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a workaround for this - what I am doing is opening the page in a new window / new tab and the functionality is working fine. It seems that the page was being wrapped in another page when navigating to it directly, which was causing the issue.

EDIT August 22, 2022 - After an update to the Edge browser that again broke this page, the team found a fix by adding the page to the sitelist.xml file.